# Block Bootstrapping using Tidymodels

Tags: r, bootstrapping, statistics-bootstrap, tidymodels, rsample

I have a **monthly (Jan - Dec)** data set for weather and crop yield. This data is collected for multiple **years (2002 - 2019)**. My aim is to obtain bootstrapped slope coefficient of the affect of temperature in each month on yield gap. In bootstrapping, I want to block the year information in a way that the function should randomly sample data from a specific year in each bootstrap rather than choosing rows from mixed years.

I read some blogs and tried different methods but I am not confident about those. I tried to disect the bootstrapped splits to ensure if I am doing it correctly but I was not.

Here is the starting code:

```r
# Load libraries
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
library(reprex)

# data 
ww_wt <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MohsinRamay/yieldgap/main/ww_wt.csv")
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> Rows: 1924 Columns: 20
#> -- Column specification --------------------------------------------------------
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr   (3): ID, Location, Month
#> dbl  (16): ...1, Year, Latitude, Longitude, YieldTrt, YieldUntrt, Mildew, Ye...
#> date  (1): Date
#> 
#> i Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> i Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

ww_wt %>% 
  select(Year, Month, gap, temp) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>    Year Month       gap  temp
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2002 September 0.282 13.6 
#> 2  2002 October   0.282 13.3 
#> 3  2002 November  0.282  7.07
#> 4  2002 December  0.282  3.44
#> 5  2002 January   0.282  5.61
#> 6  2002 February  0.282  6.93

# Bootstrapping
set.seed(123)

boots <- ww_wt %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(Year, Month, gap, temp) %>%
  nest(data = -c(Month)) %>% 
  mutate(boots = map(data, ~bootstraps(.x, times = 100, apparent = FALSE))) %>%
  unnest(boots) %>% 
  mutate(model = map(splits, ~lm(gap ~ temp, data = analysis(.))),
         coefs = map(model, tidy))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I am nesting `Months` because I want to get slopes for each month separately. Also, the data for each Year has different sample size `n` because of different number of locations each year.

Comment: Can you edit this question to create a [reprex](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/), a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can provide more effective help?

Comment: One idea I have based on what you have shared is to use `strata` argument for `bootstraps()`, and stratify on your year variable (you may want to convert it from numeric to a factor so the stratification is within each year, rather than within quartiles of the year). You might also check out the [sliding resampling options](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/slide-resampling.html), or the [CV options in timetk](https://business-science.github.io/timetk/reference/time_series_cv.html).

Comment: @JuliaSilge, I have edited the question and added the rendered reprex.

Comment: That data that you're loading is from your own C:\ drive i.e. it can't be imported by anyone except you, making it not reproducible. Can you upload your data to a site, say, Github? To read data from Github, [here's an example](https://juliasilge.com/blog/spice-girls/#explore-data)

Comment: @Desmond, thanks for pointing it out. I have added the github link for the data and it should work now. Before that, I had added a OneDrive link for this data but, indeed, it was not a good approach. I have fixed it now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do very well. You want to create bootstrap resamples for each single month/year combination? There are not many observations in each individual month. For example, there are only 9 observations in September 2002.

Comment: @JuliaSilge, I want to create bootstrap resamples for each single month. The resampling should be done in a way that rather than sampling random observations, it should sample data for a whole year and then rearrange it. For instance, I have ordered data from 2002, 2003, 2004,...,2020. But when resampled, lets say, it can be sampled and arranged as 2005, 2012, 2009,...2003 etc., for one bootstrap. Does this help?

Comment: can this be done now with  `group_bootstraps()` ?

Comment: @BenBolker Yes. Here is the updated code:

`
ww_wt %>% 
  select(Year, Month, gap, temp) %>%
  group_bootstraps(group = "Year", times = 10, apparent = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(splits = map(splits, analysis)) %>%
  unnest(splits)
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for providing these hints Julia. I think I have figured this out by just adding some extra lines of code.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'viridis'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:scales':
#> 
#>     viridis_pal

ww_wt <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MohsinRamay/yieldgap/main/ww_wt.csv")
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> Rows: 1924 Columns: 20
#> -- Column specification --------------------------------------------------------
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr   (3): ID, Location, Month
#> dbl  (16): ...1, Year, Latitude, Longitude, YieldTrt, YieldUntrt, Mildew, Ye...
#> date  (1): Date
#> 
#> i Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> i Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

set.seed(123)

# Block bootstrapping
boots <- ww_wt %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(Year, Month, gap, temp) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Month, values_from = temp, values_fn = mean) %>% 
  bootstraps(times = 10, apparent = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(splits = map(splits, analysis)) %>%
  unnest(splits) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = "Month", values_to = "temp", cols = September:August)

# Bootstraps
boots %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = row, fill = Year)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "B", direction = 1) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  facet_wrap(~Month) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.4))
```

[image]

The above plots clearly indicates that, within each bootstrap, data from each `Year` is being randomly sampled with replacement.

<sup>Created on 2022-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We don't currently have support for grouped or blocked bootstrapping; we are tracking [interest in more group-based methods here](https://github.com/tidymodels/rsample/issues/207).

If you want to create a resampling scheme that holds out whole groups of data, you might check out `group_vfold_cv()` (maybe together with `nested_cv()`?) to see if it fits your needs in the meantime. It results in a resampling scheme that looks like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

ww_wt <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MohsinRamay/yieldgap/main/ww_wt.csv")
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> Rows: 1924 Columns: 20
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr   (3): ID, Location, Month
#> dbl  (16): ...1, Year, Latitude, Longitude, YieldTrt, YieldUntrt, Mildew, Ye...
#> date  (1): Date
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

set.seed(123)
folds <-
  ww_wt %>%
  filter(Month == "September") %>%
  select(Year, Month, gap, temp) %>%
  group_vfold_cv(
    group = Year,
    v = 7
  )

folds
#> # Group 7-fold cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 7 × 2
#>   splits           id       
#>   <list>           <chr>    
#> 1 <split [135/26]> Resample1
#> 2 <split [137/24]> Resample2
#> 3 <split [133/28]> Resample3
#> 4 <split [132/29]> Resample4
#> 5 <split [142/19]> Resample5
#> 6 <split [144/17]> Resample6
#> 7 <split [143/18]> Resample7

tidy(folds) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Resample, y = Row, fill = Data)) +
  geom_tile() + scale_fill_brewer()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can bump up `v` higher if you want, and you can nest by `Month` first to do this for each Month.

Comment: Hello! I am trying to find some methods to create resamples for time series data and chanced upon your answer to this post. Could you briefly tell me what's the difference between group v-fold cv and block bootstrap? I couldn't really find any information regarding group v-fold cv on the web but from your answer, it seems to me like they are pretty much the same?

Comment: For time series, I think [you will want to use these kinds of methods](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/slide-resampling.html). That is a bit different from grouped resampling, [which is discussed pretty nicely here](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/articles/Common_Patterns.html#grouped-resampling).